# How to create relationship between tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one table for posting new articles and the content of the table is printed using a while loop.

Now I want the viewers to be able to comment on the article so I created another table for comments and a form under article in the while loop, but whenever anybody comments on the article the comment is showed with all the articles.

Because article and comments are in one while loop and there is no relationship between the tables.
tables are as follows:

content_posts(
id       int    primary auto,
subject  varchar,
postby   varchar,
date     date,
content  varchar
)

comments(
id       int    primary auto,
name     varchar,
email    varchar,
body     varchar
)

Comment: Start by updating your question with your table structure so people can suggest you what needs to be changed and then post the portion of your PHP code that does the printing so they can again suggest you what to change.

Comment: you dont need to put the comment form in while loop. and please make your question more clear with some codes or table structure.

Comment: You must store the article id in your comments table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set up a relationship you have to determine the sense of your relationship.

## One to One

Each side of the relationship is related to one and only entity. For example, nowaday, you split up the users definition in two parts :

- the connection handler (password, last login date, activation)
- the profile info (username, email, favourite movie...)

One profile has only one handler and one handler has only one profile.

In that case each table **has** to be added with  a foreign key that takes the identifier of each entity.

## One to Many

The case that you have with your blog. One article has many comments, one comments has one and only one article.

So, in your `comment` table, you have to add your foreign key that is a link to your `article.id`.
Then to select the comment that are in one article, you have to make a WHERE :

```
SELECT * FROM comment_table WHERE id_article = 1 -- for your first article,
```

If you want to load info from your article table **and** your comment table, you have to use the  `JOIN` command :

```
SELECT comment_table.*, article_table.* FROM article_table 
   JOIN comment_table ON article_table.id = comment_table.id_article
```

## many to many

each entity can be associated to many of the other. For example, il you provide tags to your articles : each tag cas be assigned to many articles, each article can have many tags.

In this case, you have to create a new table which only have `tag_id` and `article_id`. 
To select one article with his tags, you have to make a double join :

```
SELECT article.*, tags.* FROM article_table article 
    JOIN tags_in_article tia ON tia.id_article = article.id
    JOIN tag_table tags ON tia.id_tag = tag.id
    WHERE article.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try linking the tabels by the aticle id column: for example: ARTICLES with the column id and COMMENTS with a field named article_id which will contain the id of the corresponding article.
Then you can use an INNER JOIN like this

```
SELECT * FROM ARTICLES as t1 INNER JOIN COMMENTS as t2 ON t1.id = t2.article_id
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks alot, as I have one loop for article table to print its data on the page how should I print comments data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define  primary key in your article table, normally called id, and a foreign key in your comments table. This key relationship, in this case a one to many, is then used to ensure only comments related to a specific article are displayed. Using the id you would loop through the foreign keys finding the matches.

Comment: ok but should I print comments with the same loop of article or in another loop.

Comment: once you are on the article you should have the id Sayed, then use a single loop to retrieve the related comments.

Comment: You need to a foreign key to the comments table